# Express/Mongoose REST trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im running Express on my application with a `delete` route below:

```
 router.route('/lists/:id')
.delete(function(req, res){
    Entry.remove({
        _id: req.params.id
        }, function(err, list){
            if(err)
                res.send(err)

            list.title = req.body.title;

            res.json({message: 'successfully deleted'});

            console.log('DELETE on /lists/'+ req.params.id);
    });
});
```

Here is my Mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ListSchema = new Schema({
title: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('List', ListSchema);
```

When my application hits the `delete` route, my terminal logs the appropriate statement, but the model is not deleted from the database.  When I call `fetch` on the collection, all of there records are still there.

I am using a very similar approach on a different collection of data on my website, and it works fine, so Im really at a loss for why this is happening.

Comment: I have a dumb question: is the _id correct? You're using the object's mongo _id, not some id attribute that you created, right?

Comment: I set the ID in my Backbone model

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the value of `req.params.id` and the document you're expecting to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor. The type assiged is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDBs default behavior

Try passing the _id as ObjectId:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
var query = { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) };
```

Comment: This isn't necessary because Mongoose performs this casting for you.